# Ubuntu won't boot from USB it loads Grub I just dont know what else to do

Tags: 14.04

I have a HP ProBook 4440s 1.9 ghz dual core 4gb ram Sany Bridge motherboard the usb will load grub' I do not know what to do next it won't self load or install. What do I need to do?

Comment: yes, grub boots from the usb I am not familiar with the sytax of the commands to do anything else pressing TAB show an extensive list of commands

Comment: no its stops when it loads <grub/

Comment: Legacy is off Efi is turned on

Comment: windows, I hate windows

Comment: I used Linux pendrive to install Ubuntu on the usb pc boots from usb into a dos prompt

Comment: ok thanks I will try that I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: still boots into dos grub>_

Comment: how do I mark this a s solved? The usb was bad I installed Linux on three different sd cards it works great now I have to decide which one to install thanks again for your time.

Comment: Awesome, you can answer your own question and after a couple of days, you will be able to accept your own answer as the solution. Additionally, I've never been able to get SD cards to work on any of my computers, only good old USB thumb drives. Also, you can delete your old comments here to clean things up as well.